# How to set MongoDB as a windows service

Tags: mongodb

i am new user of mongodb.I have done the following steps for Installing MongoDB on Windows , Download MongoDB for Windows,
Run MongoDB, 
Start MongoDB, 
Connect to MongoDB and finally i start mongodb as window service at that time an error is found, when i enter the command "net start mongodb" in command prompt ,the following error is found,:
 The service is not responding to the control function. 
How to solve this problem?

Comment: I created everything correctly, still it fails. Simple install and setup fails. Moving over to Cassanda. Scalability will be an issue with MongoDB.

Answer (score 11):

The following works fine for me

```
mongod --install --serviceName "Mongo DB instance" --serviceDisplayName "Mongo DB instance" --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data --logpath C:\data\1.log --smallfiles
```

Of course you should change the parameters to fit your needs. Make sure that the appropriate folders exist. After installing the service you start it as follows

```
net start "Mongo DB instance"
```

Answer (score 5):

1) Download the 64 bit version of mongodb

2) Double click the downloaded file to run the installer

3) Look for MongoDB in C drive
 If you can't find it there, then look in C:\"Program Files" folder
 Cut and paste the "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" folder from C:\Program Files to C:\
 Rename "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" to MongoDB

4) Create C:\data folder

5) Now open command shell to run as Administrator

6) In the command shell you just opened:

A) Browse to C:\MongoDB\bin folder

B) Then run this command: (Change name and folder accordingly)
      mongod --install --serviceName "Mongo DB2.6 instance" --serviceDisplayName "Mongo DB2.6 instance" --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data --logpath C:\data\1.log --smallfiles

C) To start the service, you can either run this command: net start "Mongo DB2.6 instance"
      OR type services in the Search for programs and files box. Then look for Mongo DB2.6 instance > right click it and choose Start

D) Verify that you can connect and run command
      Open a command prompt

```
       >cd C:\MongoDB\bin (enter)
       >mongo.exe (enter)
       >it will show that it is connected
       >type command "show dbs" and hit enter
       >it will show local and test dbs
```

Answer (score 2):

follow this nice article with latest mongo version 2.4.9: [Install, setup and start MongoDB on Windows](http://blog.ajduke.in/2013/04/10/install-setup-and-start-mongodb-on-windows/), is very simple~

Answer (score 2):

I wrote one of the above articles and while trying to upgrade to 3.0.3, I figured out at least 2 instances that causes the above error:

A) The `\data\db` directory doesn't exist or is not being pointed to correctly in the configuration file.

B) The `\log` directory doesn't exist or is not being pointed to correctly in the configuration file.

Comment: There's a third situation in which this happens.  If you install to a path with spaces, the config argument isn't quoted correctly int the service registry key.  See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12502

Comment: I can confirm that having a path with spaces is still an issue today. Install MongoDB to a path without any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps described here ?
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#mongodb-as-a-windows-service

PS: I tried and it is working fine for me.

Update: The solution described in the following link works
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5275

Comment: am also tried the steps.But in the last step "net start mongodb" an error "The service is not responding to the control function" and also when i start the MongoDB service (Control panel->Administrative tools->services)found an error 1053:The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.So, how it solve?

Comment: Can you try the solution described here? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5275

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link to the letter **[Install, setup and start MongoDB on Windows (on Windows 8.1](http://www.troubleshootingcenter.com/2014/04/19/installing-mongodb-2-6-and-configuring-it-as-a-windows-service-windows-8-1/)** and had the same error.

I discovered I forgot to create a log folder as instructed and when I corrected that it worked for me and was able to make it an automatic service at run up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turns out I had named my log folder "logs" and the config file was pointed to "log". Changed the folder name and it was all good.